# Defer imports with babel

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, sinon, systemjs

I am working on a large ReactJS based website and need to write some test where I can defer loading of various modules because I need to have Sinon set up first.

The basic setup looks like this

```
const assert = require('chai').assert;
const sinon = require('sinon');
const reducerUtils = require('../../app/utils/reducerUtils');
const connectToReducerStub = sinon.stub(
  reducerUtils,
  'connectToReducer',
  (stateMap, actionMap) => { console.log(`Connecting to reducer`); }
);
```

At this point I just need to import a component that tries to use `reducerUtils.connectToReducer` that I've stubbed away, but my issue is that if I do like everywhere else in the codebase:

```
import MyComponent from '../../app/components/myComponent.jsx';
```

The import is run as the first thing (before everything else), making the import to- and call to `reducerUtils.connectToReducer` take place before I get to stub it away.

On the other hand, trying to just defer it by using `require` doesn't seem to work:

```
const MyComponent = require('../../app/components/myComponent.jsx');
```

What happens here is that `MyComponent` is just `undefined`.

I'm using ES6 classes to define my components along the lines of:

```
import react from 'react';
import connectToReducer from '../../utils/reducerUtils';

class MyComponent {
  ...
}

export connectToReducer(<stateMap>, <actionMap>)(MyComponent);
```

After having played around with trying to make `require` work, I gave up and tried SystemJS as an alternative module loader, but it doesn't resolve paths the same way that `require` does, so it seems that most module paths have to be set up by hand.

Answer (score 1):

`import` statements are executed before the rest of your module, as you noticed. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29330452/893780) for more info.

It should work with `require()`, but because ES6 modules have a notion of a *"default import/export"* (which you're using), and `require()` doesn't, the workaround is that the default exports is made accessible through the `default` property.

In other words:

```
const MyComponent = require('../../app/components/myComponent.jsx').default;
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually I found a bug in my code making the `require` fail. Once the bug was removed, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `connectToReducerStub` must return the original component or the component wrapped another component:

```
const connectToReducerStub = sinon.stub(
  reducerUtils,
  'connectToReducer',
  (stateMap, actionMap) => {
    return component => {
      const props = ...
      const wrapper = <MyWrapper><component {...props} /></MyWrapper>;
      return wrapper;
    };
  }
);
```