# reactjs, bootstrap and npm import - jQuery is not defined

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I'm trying to use bootstrap in my react app, but it gives me a`Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery`. I have imported jquery and have tried tried the following from other posts:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
global.jQuery = $;
```

However, I still get the `not defined` error.

The only way to fix this is to put

```
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

into index.html

is there a way to export jquery or have bootstrap be able to detect/read it?

I call my bootstrap via

```
import bootstrap from 'bootstrap'
```

Comment: If you go to your project folder, run node in CLI with `node` command, and type `require('jquery')` in REPL, does it return a function? Asking just to make sure you have this dependency added to yarn lockfile.

Comment: Just used `create-react-app` with `jQuery` recently, it's not `react-react-app` side problem.

Comment: @RishatMuhametshin Yes it returns a function

Comment: @Xlee I can use jquery inside the react part, e.g `$("#select");` works. It's mainly an issue with DataTables as it requires jQuery to be visible/usable by the window/global

Comment: Where do you put your bootstrap js? Please post your more html content.

Comment: @blackmiaool I call it via `import`.

Comment: @A.Lau  What's the order between it and jquery then?  More code pls

Comment: @blackmiaool I call jquery first, doing that little passage at the start, then call bootstrap. Well at least I tried, now I just have the jquery CDN in my index.html head.

Comment: @A.Lau Did you try my answer? It works well for me.

Comment: @blackmiaool I will have to try it in a couple of days when I'm back at work. Didn't even notice it.

Comment: @A.Lau  It's ok. I thought it's because my code doesn't work or something :)

Comment: @blackmiaool I'm also using ES6 style imports, so hopefully that still works with my syntax

Comment: @A.Lau Sure it does. I have tested it in *create-react-app* environment. And I also use `import` in the first line of my code.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## <del>`import bootstrap from 'bootstrap'`</del>

## `const bootstrap = require('bootstrap');`

I tried to build a project with "create-react-app" and found that the loading order of imported modules is not same with importing order. And this is the reason why boostrap can't find jquery. Generally, you can use "require" in this condition. It works on my pc.

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
global.jQuery = $;
const bootstrap = require('bootstrap');
console.log(bootstrap)
```

Relevant things:

#### `imports` are hoisted

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29334761/4831179

#### `imports` should go first

> Notably, imports are hoisted, which means the imported modules will be evaluated before any of the statements interspersed between them. Keeping all imports together at the top of the file may prevent surprises resulting from this part of the spec.

from https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/first.md

Comment: weird how I can't use `import bootstrap from 'bootstrap';`

Answer (score 5):

Are you using webpack? If so, add this on your `webpack.config.js`.

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    $: 'jquery'
  })
],
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using create-react-app, so I don't think I can configure the webpack stuff. I'm going to try eject it and see what happens.

Comment: You are using create-react-app, not webpack. In that case, how about `var $ = require('jquery');` and `window.$ = $;`, `window.jQuery = $;` I'm sorry I'm not well why it works, but might be help, maybe.

Answer (score 3):

When using create-react-app,
First You need to install the Jquery package like this.

```
sudo npm install jquery --save
```

and react-bootstrap like this

```
 sudo npm install react-bootstrap --save
```

Now in the JS files you can use both jquery and bootstrap like this.

```
 import $ from 'jquery';
 import { Carousel, Modal,Button, Panel,Image,Row,Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

you can use this url for react bootstrap components 
      https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html

you can use Buttons with onclick function like this

```
<Button bsStyle="primary" bsSize="large" active onClick={this.getData()}>Sample onClick</Button>
```

in the

```
 getData(){
 $.ajax({
   method: 'post',
   url:'http://someurl/getdata',
   data: 'passing data if any',
   success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
      alert(data);
      this.setState({
         some: data.content,
         some2: data.content2,
      });
   },
   error: function(err){
      console.log(err);
   }
 });
```

all of this is basic example using jquery and bootstrap if you need more you can write comments about this.

Comment: was hoping more of a way to use it with the standard bootstrap as I'm a little more familiar with that. Only thing not working with the normal bootstrap is importing jQuery, which works if I do it in the HTML `head`.

Comment: after installing the react bootstrap you can also use the normal bootstrap components like writing the css class names to the div elements.by giving the bootstrap cdn in your header file.The basic problem you will face is it will load for the first time fine,later in the routings of next page the bootstrap may cause problems like not loading correctly.

Comment: Please don't use sudo for npm installs…

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I see from your comments your issue seems to be on integrating datatables with jquery, you should consider re-formulating your question.

Bear in mind React uses a *virtual* DOM, and jQuery plays entirely in the DOM.

So considering that, it seems near impossible to get DataTables & jQuery to play nice all around. You could get DataTables displayed, but when you do anything else with React, it basically goes back to using its own *virtual* DOM, which would mess with the DataTables.

**Some react friendly datatables alternatives**:

- **[React data grid](http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/examples.html#/filterable-grid)**
- **[Integrate DataTables with ReactJS](https://gist.github.com/checkraiser/8555856)** (note `destroy` option is used to get it to work)
- **[Facebook FixedDataTable](https://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/example-object-data.html)**
- **[NPM react-bootstrap-datatable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datatable-bootstrap)**

**DataTables related discussions:**

- **[DataTable with ReactJS](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/32186/datatable-with-reactjs)**
- **[Anyone use DataTables with ReactJS?](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/31761/anyone-use-datatables-with-reactjs)**

Comment: well the thing is, I can get it to work by putting jquery into the index.html header. Just doesn't feel right since I've npm installed jquery

Comment: @A.Lau yes, I agree not ideal considering npm but seems to be the only workaround so far. I'd say that if it benefits your project without any downsides, go ahead and load it via html's head.