# How to import external javascript (which requires jquery) in reactjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, npm

First of all I'm still a newbie in web development. Okay, now to the question.
I have these imports:

```
import $ from 'jquery'; 
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
global.jQuery = $;
import './assets/js/waves';
```

How do I properly import an external javascript to reactjs if my external javascript requires jquery?

Because based on what these guys have said:

> [reactjs, bootstrap and npm import - jQuery is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41818089/reactjs-bootstrap-and-npm-import-jquery-is-not-defined)
>
> [Are ES6 module imports hoisted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29329662/are-es6-module-imports-hoisted/29334761#29334761)

my imports will be hoisted, which results in my external "***./assets/js/waves***" js causing an error.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined?
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about this
var $ = require('./lib/jquery.js');
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $

Comment: what about require(pathtojquery) ?

Comment: or `import from 'pathtojquery'`

Comment: Thanks @HemaNandagopal and ArslArsl. I tried those but still did not load. Even the jquery is not loading. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have the jquery plugin cdn or check the whether the script is there in the path which you refered,

Comment: @HemaNandagopal its there. Hmm. Also, I failed to mention I installed jquery through npm.

Comment: Have you installed it globally ? instead of import $ from 'jquery'; 
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $; try  var $ = require ('jquery') ;

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
```

Then you have a reference of `jQuery` and you may do with it what you like, for instance:

```
window.$ = jQuery;
```

Comment: thanks @ideaboxer but somehow it still did not work. question, where do you think should I put this? In a component or in the parent (index)?

Comment: It must have something to do with the content of the *waves.js* file. Could you post (part of) its content so that we can analyze it?