# Import external script with jQuery to React JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, cordova

I want to include an external Javascript(with jQuery) to reactjs.

I did take a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44972038/how-to-import-external-javascript-which-requires-jquery-in-reactjs), but there are still some error.

I have a external JS file, called **external.js**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, 
});


function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log("The device is ready");
}
```

In **index.html**, i add the `<script src="external.js"></script>` to the script:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <script src="external.js"></script>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Inside the React js project, I added the following code to **App.js**:

```
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
window.$ = jQuery;
```

However, when I run the reactJS project with command `npm start`, inside the console, it shows

> external.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

What should I do in order to include the external js file and also the jQuery?

Comment: Are you using webpack?

Comment: I am using npm for building the React js app

Comment: So, you don't have a webpack.config file?

Comment: I don't have `webpack.config` file

Comment: Are you able to show us your index.html file?

Comment: I know the reason behind your problem. App.js is called after the document load or at least after the call for external.js script. It will be helpful to take a look at the index.html file to think of the best solution.

Comment: Updated the question with the index.html file

Comment: you are only including one script (external.js) in your html file? Where is the main script of your app?

Comment: Actually Im very new to React JS. There are two more js files: App.js and index.js. When I type `npm start`, it will automatically compile the code.

Comment: Which one of them depends on the other one? I am guessing index.js is your root script? If so, I would like you to add a script tag, and reference to this script, and make sure that it comes before the external.js script element.

Comment: Thanks, it works after putting the include jquery before including the external js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your external script is executed before the statement `window.$ = jQuery`. Try to include the jQuery (before the inclusion of the external script) like you included the external script