# ES6 import in iteration & not at top-level

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, babel-polyfill

This is really 2 questions in 1...

I have a Node backend with an Express middleware. On entry of the application, I am **trying** to load in express routes though an iteration. Previously this was done with [requirejs](http://www.requirejs.org/) but I am wanting to scrap all that out and use es6's import/export instead.

My current code *(based on [MEAN.js](https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/master/config/lib/express.js#L174))*:

```
let initModulesServerPolicies = (app) => {
    forEach(config.files.server.policies, (policyPath) => {
        require(path.resolve(policyPath)).invokeRolesPolicies();
    });
};
```

I am trying to somehow get my code to be like this:

```
let initModulesServerPolicies = (app) => {
    forEach(config.files.server.policies, (policyPath) => {
        import path.resolve(policyPath).invokeRolesPolicies();
    });
};
```

Now, the main error that appears here is:

> 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level

I can continue to use *requirejs* but that will require me changing my es6 exports in those policy files back to `module.exports`.

I am using `babel-polyfill` to enable me to use es6 import/export on the server.

**N.B.:** `config.files.server.policies` will be an array of relative paths. This array size will frequently change as I will add/deduct modules from my app which is why it would be preferable not to import these explicitly and an iteration is much more preferable.

So my 2 questions are:

1. Can import/export be encapsulated within a function *(so not at top level)*
2. Can multiple files be imported via an iteration?

I expect these kind of hiccups when I am trying to use es6 code as it is not fully supported yet so if this cannot be done then I'll find another way.

Comment: No, `import` and `export` can only appear at the outermost nesting level of the module. They cannot even be inside a normal statement (like a `while` loop block).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29329662/are-es6-module-imports-hoisted