# import is not recognized inside function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I have a function that uses some constants that are exported in seperate file.

If I import the constants inside the function it is not working :

```
export function findLocalizedLabelForValueDomainCode(...) {
    import LOCALE from  './constants';
   // doing staff 
}
```

however if I replace :

```
import LOCALE from  './constants';
```

by

```
let cst = require( './constants');
```

it works... have you an idea why I cant use the import syntax in this case ?

FYI : My project is using ES6

Comment: Import have to be at the root of the scope: you can't import into a function / class / method...

Comment: imports need to be outside of functions, is there any particular reason you need to import inside of the function?

Comment: You can find your answer here: <https://stackoverflow.com/a/29330452/8419483>

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic importing is currently in stage 2 proposal but you can use it with babel plugin -> https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import/