# Environment variables only working when dotenv is imported and configured in each file (instead of just in index.ts)

Tags: node.js, typescript, dotenv

I should only need to do:

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();
```

in the index.js file. But my `.env` variables only work when I explicitly import and configure dotenv in each file that uses .env variables.

This is my `tsconfig.json` :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDirs": ["src"],
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "lib": ["es2020"],
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "types": ["node"]
  },

}
```

Not sure why, any ideas?

`index.ts`:
[image]

`connectToDatabase.ts`
[image]

`.env`
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Imports [are hoisted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29329662/are-es6-module-imports-hoisted), so your `dotenv.config` isn't being called until *after* the rest of your imports. To make this work with one import/config call, you can put that in a separate file and import that instead:

```js
// env.ts
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()
```

```js
// index.ts
import './env'
// followed by all your other imports
```

And in the future, please post your code, not screenshots of your code. It's faster and easier to just copy-paste!

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()
```

would do the work. for more information visit https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#how-do-i-use-dotenv-with-import